# How do you make a smooth and creamy apple custard?

Tags: custard

I've been trying to figure out how to make a creamy custard ( like for a creme brulee) infused with apple (or any kind of fruit/berry) while keeping a creamy texture and avoiding chunks. Ive thought about cooking down the apples then heating the cream with the apples and then straining it into the eggs but im worried that the cream may become too thin from the water in the apples. Any ideas for how to accomplish this? I havn't had much luck looking online.

Comment: Anything you tried already? What were the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Bake** the apples and have them **dry and crisp up (cut the apples thin so that they dry up evenly and crisp faster)** and concentrate the flavour. Then blend to a powder and mix into the custard.
2. **Cook and reduce** the apples till a **very tender** gooey apple pie texture comes and then thicken and reduce excess water as to not thin out the custard, **mash till homogenized** and fold in with custard.
3. Get something like apple juice and **reduce till thick** and add sugar to make syrup and use that in addition or in place (depending how much you want in) of the sugar for the custard recipe.

Personally I'd go with the first option though time consuming.

Comment: Have you tried either of the first two? The texture of having the actual apple pulp will be there, I think.

Comment: As a powder it won't mess with the custard too much; treat it kinda like the sugar in the custard recipe so the first is my more favored. Though the second can be tricky hence the "folding" it in rather than mixing so thats why I prefer the first option.

Comment: Also I have tried the 1st for a creme brûlée actually and it worked fine the custard is still cooling right now but it seems to have the proper consistency. The second option I'm only extrapolating based on other recipes I've used in the past.

Comment: Hmmm. I would bet the texture will be noticeable. Creme brulee is a really sooth texture, and the apple pulp will still be there. I'll try it as well...

Comment: Had it for breakfast seems to have worked fine, just be sure the powder is very fine